# Disable javascript pausing background events during alert or confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I have two different  functions in javascript.
Function A) is a function, which shows a countdown on the page.
Function B) , the other function is completely indepentent from function A).

But, when I start an alert() or confirm() in function B), the countdown in function A) pauses. So every background script is pausing.

Is there a way to disable the pause without changing the alert() or confirm() to jquery?
This script is only running on one specific machine, so I also could change some parameters in the browser.

thanks in advance

Comment: alert, prompt and confirm will stop ny JS executing. Change it to [dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message)

Comment: Note that JavaScript is a single-threaded language. So whenever something blocks the thread, it's just blocked. I hope I understood your question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - not a good duplicate since the accepted answer STILL uses alert - this one is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544300/show-javascript-alert-without-blocking-javascript

Comment: That's right, but the point of the question is to ask if the background script can still run while the alert/confirm is visible.

Comment: Ok, andrusieczko and mplungjan gave me the answer. The answer was good, but I hoped, I could do it without changing all my dialogue-boxes.