# Load Javascript Alert while the page is loading

Tags: javascript, alert, loading

Im wondering if its possible to load a JavaScript alert before the content
while the page is loading

Whatever I try to do the alert fires and the page doesn't load until the alert is closed

```html
<script>
    alert('But wait, there\'s more...');
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show javascript Alert without blocking javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544300/show-javascript-alert-without-blocking-javascript)

Comment: no it doesn't , still thank you 
I want to load a popup alert with JavaScript while the page continues loading

Comment: Did you try it yourself? If you place an alert within a script tag in a plain HTML page with some lorem ipsum text. The alert will be shown even before the text content is fully rendered

Comment: yes but my page loads for 40 seconds

Comment: The native alert will BLOCK the page rendering. If you want to display the alert but also keep the content loading, you will need to find a third-party library.

Comment: By the way, if your page(s) take 40 seconds to load, you will need to find out which resources are taking so long to load. A site should be loaded within a second or two.

Comment: my page loads loads for 40 seconds on purpose 
and where can I find a third party library ?

Comment: You can start with GitHub with libraries that have 1. most starred, 2. regularly maintained, 3. well documented, and a proper license

Comment: `alert` is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can try this : $(document).ready(function)

You can create a function containing the alert, and put it like a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a third party library, just add some sort of loading alert, style to your liking and when the document has loaded remove it from the DOM. The back drop is only there to add a bit of opacity.

```js
const alertElm = document.getElementById('loading-alert');

setTimeout(() => { document.body.removeChild(alertElm); }, 2000);
```

```css
.alert-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.alert-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.alert-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert-container" id="loading-alert">
  <div class="alert-backdrop"></div>
  <div class="alert-content">
    ...loading
  </div>
</div>
Here is the rest of your page visible under the back drop.
```